# replace pattern in text file

Tags: linux, bash

Below my sample html file:

```
some text here <img src="http://site.com/7b399e20/77165/5fa/2a31ffb8.jpg"/> sometext here

some text here <img src="http://site.com/7b399e20/2a31ffb8.jpg"/> sometext here

some text here <img src="http://site.com/7b399e20/2a31ffb8.png"/> sometext here

some text here <img src="http://site.com/2a31ffb8.jpeg"/> sometext here
```

how do I make such a transformation:

```
some text here <img src="web/2a31ffb8.jpg"/> sometext here

some text here <img src="web/2a31ffb8.jpg"/> sometext here

some text here <img src="web/2a31ffb8.png"/> sometext here

some text here <img src="web/2a31ffb8.jpeg"/> sometext here
```

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'll use Perl, because I know the syntax without having to look it up, but it would be very similar in awk or sed, as tekknolagi says:

```
perl -pi -e 's|http://site.com/.*([^/]+)"/>|web/$1"/>|;'  <filename>
```

This will preserve everything between the last / and the "

Comment: It will fail on lines when there are `"` chars after closing the `img src="..."` part as this regex can be greedy.

Comment: +1. Perl's the way to go for this kind of thing although your regexp would  munge other URLs in the file as well which might not be desired.

Comment: @ZsoltBotykai: true. I have edited the script to make it pickier.

Comment: @ColinFine still no good. It will match the whole string (e.g.): `http://site.com/valamisemmi.jpg" akarmi " barmi " semmi "`

Comment: @ZsoltBotykai: No, only where the " is immediately followed by />

Comment: @ColinFine Why yes, so with this example snippet will match: `img src="http://site.com/something.jpg"/><a src=http://example.com"/>` this part: `http://site.com/something.jpg"/><a src=http://example.com"/>`.

Comment: @ZsoltBotykai: true. Again, it depends how defensive you need to be, which in turn depends on what assumptions you can make about what is in the file.

Answer (score 1):

```
sed -i 's:\(img src="\).*\(/[^"/]\+\.[^"]\+"\):\1web\2:' INPUTFILE
```

Might do it in place.

HTH

Answer (score -1):

What about using perl script? I have put your sample text into file `foo.txt` and here is the result:

```
$ cat foo.txt | perl -pe 's#http://.*/([a-z0-9A-Z]*\.)#web/\1#'
some text here <img src="web/2a31ffb8.jpg"/> sometext here
some text here <img src="web/2a31ffb8.jpg"/> sometext here
some text here <img src="web/2a31ffb8.png"/> sometext here
some text here <img src="web/2a31ffb8.jpeg"/> sometext here
```

Comment: Won't work correctly if there are more non `img` related links are on the line (greedy regex).